# How to measure Docker Hub image pulls for free account user (reference to new policy by Docker Hub from 1. Nov 2020)?

Tags: docker, api, dockerhub

I have two questions:

1. As Docker Hub is updating their image pull and retention policy from *1. November 2020* and particularly restricting the image pull requests for free user account. I want to measure how many pull requests (GET) for images as well as manifests has been made by a free user account. Is there a docker hub api that gives this metadata?
2. How to verify the docker pulled image is downloaded by a particular user?

Thank you,
Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Docker is going to update their policy regarding image pull rates (and of course other resources) by anonymous user and authenticated user from 2. November 2020, they provide a header (metadata) to measure the Rate Limit and remaining quota.
See below:

Get Bearer Token:

```
$ TOKEN=$(curl "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry-1.docker.io&scope=repository:ratelimitpreview/test:pull" | jq -r .token)
```

Get manifest to measure assigned and left quota:

```
$ curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ratelimitpreview/test/manifests/latest 2>&1 | grep RateLimit

## Output:

< RateLimit-Limit: 200;w=21600
< RateLimit-Remaining: 199;w=21600 

# w -> time in seconds
# RateLimit-Limit -> Assigned Pulls Quota for w seconds
# RateLimit-Remaining -> Remaining Pulls Quota for w seconds
```

**Update:**

See the official blog from docker -  https://www.docker.com/blog/checking-your-current-docker-pull-rate-limits-and-status/